# libEGL: eglMakeCurrentImpl:1038 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS) with lazyGrid android compose

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, android-jetpack-compose, android-videoview

I am working with lazyGrid from android-compose to display a grid of videos like bellow

[image]

and I am showing the video feed using a custom view from a third party library.

For now everything works well, problems come when I try to reorder video tiles (eg. last one take place of first and so on): Some videos become frozen and some others become green.

and this is what I see on the log

```
E/libEGL: eglMakeCurrentImpl:1038 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
E/Render: eglMakeCurrent failed
E/Render: EGL error = 0x3002
E/Render: cannot swap buffers!
```

Screen:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    ...
) {
    items(items = members, key = { id }) { member ->

       val context = LocalContext.current
       AndroidView(factory = {
       Renderer(context, ...).apply {
          layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
       }
    }
 }
```

Custom view:

```
public class Renderer extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
   private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
   private EGLDisplay mEglDisplay;
   private EGLSurface mEglSurface;
   private EGLContext mEglContext;
   private EGL10 mEgl;
   private EGLConfig eglConfig;
   private GL10 mGl;

   ... //some code for creating the surface
}
```

Any ideas please ?  what can cause the EGL_BAD_ACCESS and buffers issues ?

I don't have good knowledge on open-gl

Comment: Need something closer to a minimal viable reproducer here I think. How are these used? From what threads?

Comment: Basically I have a list of members, for each member I am creating a new Renderer, and it's on main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is happening because I am creating multiple `TextureView`s on top each others which the `TextureView` does not allow. I need to disconnect the old `TextureView` from the parent before creating new one or moving other on top of it.

The solution is to use `SurfaceView` view instead of `TextureView`